# Get data from object in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, object, plsql

I have an SQL function, which returns an object.

```
select some_function(acctID) from dual;
```

The above returns an object like

```
[CISADM.CM_MTR_READ_OBJ]
```

I need to get individual values from the object.

Comment: the funtion is very big i'll add the returning object

Comment: return_obj := cm_mtr_read_obj(readdttm, reg_reading, read_type, reader_rem_cd);
    RETURN return_obj;

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171637/java-reflection-how-to-get-field-value-from-an-object-not-knowing-its-class) for reading value in Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How the returning result is displayed heavily depends on a client you are using to execute that query. It would be better if you explicitly specified those properties of an object instance you want to be displayed. For example:

```
create or replace type T_Obj as object(
  prop1 number,
  prop2 date
)  

create or replace function F_1(
   p_var1 in number,
   p_var2 in date
 ) return t_obj is
 begin
   return t_obj(p_var1, p_var2);
 end;

select t.obj.prop1
     , t.obj.prop2
 from (select F_1(1, sysdate) as obj
         from dual) t
```

result:

```
 OBJ.PROP1  OBJ.PROP2
----------  -----------
         1  25-Oct-2013
```