# Java XML dynamic parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm looking for a simple solution.

I have a xml file:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <class>java.lang.String</class>
        <value>String value...</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <class>java.lang.Boolean</class>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <!-- ... others java lang wrapper class -->
</properties>
```

I would like to do a dynamic parser.

I know that I can read the xml with org.w3c.dom.* and org.w3c.dom.Node.getTextContent() I can get the value of the tag.

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(classTextContent);
// How to convert value to specific clazz?
// if/else (clazz)? Does not look a nice answer.
```

Any suggestion?

**[Edited] By reflection:**

The variable "clazz " is a java.lang.Class, right?
How can I convert textContent value (in String) to any wrapper type?

```
Object objectValue = null;
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(nodeClass.getTextContent());
String value = nodeValue.getTextContent();
if (clazz.equals(Boolean.class) { objectValue = Boolean.valueOf(value) }
```

**valueOf** could be a generic method that I could call using reflection...
Integer, Float, Boolean, Long, Double support **valueOf**.

Another way?

Comment: Reflection is your answer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 0):

```
Object object = YourClass.class.getConstructor(new Class<?>[]{}).newInstance();

// if you want to use a constructor, let's say, for YourClass(int name, int id)

Object object = YourClass.class.getConstructor(new Class<?>[]{int.class, int.class}).newInstance(desiredName, desiredId);
```

Comment: Emd4600 please take a look into my edited question. Thanks

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16172206/3779214, making the user specify the field to fill with the value.