# Java Array Name from the request parameter

Tags: java

I have an array

> String[] strArray= {"Milk","Bread,"eggs"};

and generally we can display the values as strArray[i] in a loop ... however I am getting the name of the array " StrArray"  dynamically from a value of a request parameter &arrayName=strArray .

> request.getParameter("arrayName");

Can one of you experts kindly advise how to construct the arrayname from the request and use it to display the values of the array.

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: You already know (and show) how to get the name from a parameter.  Your best bet for accessing the array by dynamically-provided name is to store the array (and any others that you want to access that way) in a `Map`, with their names as keys.  At runtime, retrieve them from the map.

Comment: based on request paramter I will have to  display the values in my application , for example if the value of the request is strArray then will get the values displayed from strArray..

Comment: If you're talking about doing this in a servlet / JSP, then you could consider storing the array as a request, session, or context attribute instead of in a Map.

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you give me an example?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, its java only.. I am using the piece of code in SAP.

Comment: Around here we expect you to do a fair share of the research and work.  If you do not know how to use a Map and cannot figure it out from its API docs and the many available online tutorials, then maybe you should consider another line of work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sure i will consider, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest but unclean way would be a map:

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
map.put("strArray", strArray);
map.get("strArray");
```

Probably better would be to use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html).
[stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171637/java-reflection-how-to-get-field-value-from-an-object-not-knowing-its-class)

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, String[]> strMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

strMap.put("strArray", new String[]{"Milk","Bread,"eggs"});

String strName[]=(String[])strMap.get(request.getParameter("strArray"));

response.write(strName[1]);
```

this works.