# Java set generic Value of an Object in an ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, methods

I have a class

```
 public class ValueObject<T> {
        private T value;

        public void setValue(T value){
          this.value = value
        }
    }
```

In another class I have an Array of the Objects from the first Class

```
ArrayList<ValueObject<?>> valueObjects = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> valueNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

now I want to write a Method which looks in a second array for a name and assigns a new value to an instance of the first object in that arrayList

```
ValueObject<?> get(String name) {
        return valueObjects.get(valueNames.indexOf(name));
}

public <T> void set(String name, T value) {
     get(name).setValue(value);
}
```

But I don't get this to work. Do I need to write something with ? in the set() Method?

Thanks

Comment: avoid `value = value` should be `this.value = value`

Comment: Lets say your ValueObject<?> had a `String` `value` but you call `set` with `Integer`, how would compiler be able to prevent it?

Comment: What's `ValueNames`? And what's `valueNames`? And why are you passing one instance to another? And why do you think you can call `setValue()` with any `T`?

Comment: This might help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171637/java-reflection-how-to-get-field-value-from-an-object-not-knowing-its-class

Comment: ok corrected my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide a full example, so not sure which will help you.

Version 1 if you can use `List<ValueObject<T>>` because all `ValueObjects` hold the same type.

```
static class Lookup<T2> {

    List<ValueObject<T2>> valueObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> valueNames = new ArrayList<>();

    ValueObject<T2> get(String name) {
        return valueObjects.get(valueNames.indexOf(name));
    }

    public void set(String name, T2 value) {
        get(name).setValue(value);
    }
}
```

Version 2 if `valueObjects` really contains `ValueObject` with different contained classes:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static class Lookup2 {

    List<ValueObject<?>> valueObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> valueNames = new ArrayList<>();

    /* unsafe get */
    ValueObject<?> get(String name) {
        return valueObjects.get(valueNames.indexOf(name));
    }


    /* set using unsafe get */
    public <T> void setUnsafe(String name, T value) {
        /* might add handling of runtime exceptions */
        ((ValueObject<T>)get(name)).setValue(value);
    }

    /* safe get when client knows class */
    <T> ValueObject<T> get(String name, Class<T> clazz) {
        /* might do instanceOf check here to throw custom exception */
        return (ValueObject<T>) valueObjects.get(valueNames.indexOf(name));
    }

    /* set using safe get */
    public <T> void set(String name, T value) {
        /* might add handling of runtime exceptions */
        get(name, (Class<T>) value.getClass()).setValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The second solution worked great =)