# Convert object to map in java

Tags: java

how I can convert Object to `Map<String, String>` 
where `key` is `obj.parameter.name` and `value` is `obj.parameter.value`

for exaple: `Object obj = new myObject("Joe", "Doe");` convert to `Map` with keys: name, surname and values: Joe, Doe.

Comment: what is `obj`, what is `parameter`, ... what is the input, what is the expected output?

Comment: You'll want to use Java reflection. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171637/java-reflection-how-to-get-field-value-from-an-object-not-knowing-its-class#16172206) may help you.

Comment: for exaple: `Object obj = new myObject("Joe", "Doe");` convert to `Map` with keys: name, surname and values Joe, Doe

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This has potential to raise many issues especially relating to scoping (only public variables can be fetched, not even default ones). Is there something you're looking to do with this? There is likely a better solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how you'd do it:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main {
    public int a = 3;
    public String b = "Hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> map = parameters(new Main());
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> parameters(Object obj) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try { map.put(field.getName(), field.get(obj)); } catch (Exception e) { }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Basically, you use reflection to get all of the fields in the class. Then, you access all of those fields of the object. Keep in mind that this only works for fields accessible from the method that gets the fields.

Answer (score 31):

Apart from the trick solution using reflection, you could also try `jackson` with one line as follows:

```
objectMapper.convertValue(o, Map.class);
```

---

A test case:

```
    @Test
    public void testConversion() {
        User user = new User();
        System.out.println(MapHelper.convertObject(user));
    }

    @Data
    static class User {
        String name = "Jack";
        boolean male = true;
    }


// output: you can have the right type normally
// {name=Jack, male=true}
```

Comment: Where is `MapHelper` defined/provided from?

Comment: @fragmentedreality Untested but I think something this will work: https://gist.github.com/qb20nh/5354dba41827cad3e72caeaf50659b9b

Comment: @MondayFatigue a simple Map.class will work too

Comment: When I do this it converts everything in the hashmap to a string

Comment: If you need a typed map, this worked for me:

Map<String,Object> objMap = objectMapper.convertValue(obj,TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(HashMap.class,String.class,Object.class));

Comment: The only disadvantage to this can be that this does a deep conversion, so if there are objects inside the object, it will create a map inside your map (or fail the conversion if it doesn't know how to convert the object). Maybe this is what you want, but in some cases you want a shallow conversion, so in that case this solution doesn't work. You'd want @hyper-neutrino 's solution in that case.

Comment: More generic approach: MAPPER.convertValue(structure, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {})