# Set all text fields fielddata true using java and elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

How can I set all text fields fielddata true using java and elasticsearch?
I want to sort products using a field from features. However features is a dynamic object, I can't predicate what will be its keys.
The problem is how to set all features attributes fielddata true.
this is my model:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;


@Document(indexName = "product", type = "product")
public class ProductSearchModel {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, fielddata = true)
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested , fielddata = true)
    private CategorySearchModel brand;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text , fielddata = true)
    private String code;

    private Object features;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

 

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Object getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    public void setFeatures(Object features) {
        this.features = features;
    }

   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you parse the Object to a Map or a Json or something?.

If yes, run through its keys and set the value to true?

Examples:

- [Convert object to map in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52406467/convert-object-to-map-in-java)
- [Converting Java objects to JSON with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson)
- [How to iterate over a JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject)

Comment: thank you for replying, but my question is how to set feilddata of fields in the dynamic object  true.