# Convert Object to Map<String,Object>in Java

Tags: java, reactive, flux, collectors

I have a piece of code.

```
List<Bson> results = queryBuilder.createQuery(request, tableName, pivotValues);
Publisher<Employee> rows = getCollection().aggregate(results);
Flux.from(rows).map().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

inside map() function - I need to write a lambda expression to convert the Employee object to Map<String, Object> - String Key is field name and Object is field value. Employee has fields id and name.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert object to map in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52406467/convert-object-to-map-in-java)