# Casting type Object into List<Object>

Tags: java, spring

A remote call to an API controlleur (via RestTemplate) (that is returning a List ([]) of known object from one side and an unknown type of object from the remote side) is returning an `ResponseEntity<Object>` (the call is made via `restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object.class)`

In order to iterate / loop through the object returned is it possible to cast the returned object to List (given that it is a List ) ? and use Java's reflection to get wanted fields values from each object ?
Otherwise how to access the Object Type to get fields values?

EDIT : 
The object having this structure (and is of type Object in java)

```
{id=5, name=Jasmin, description=Room Jasmin, idType=0, addedAt=2020-06-16T17:20:00.617+0000, modifiedAt=null, deleted=true, images=[string], idBuilding=2, idFloor=4, idZone=3}
```

How to access the id field value ?
I tried with `Class<?> RoomClass = roomTuple.getClass();`and then with `getField()`

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried changing `Object.class` to `List.class`? Also, [API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)

Comment: Do you know object type when use in `restTemplate.getForEntity` ?

Comment: @gabrielgarcia, nice idea i will try it

Comment: @Eklavya Yes it is an object from a distant microservicces where the object is defined as a class and attributes

Comment: @lopmkipm Then you can create a class using those attribute right ?

Comment: @Eklavya already did and calling an instance of that class, which is an object in the other class / microservices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define response type first using `ParameterizedTypeReference`

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MicroServiceClass>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MicroServiceClass>>() {};
```

And then use `RestTemplate#exchange` using your responseType

```
ResponseEntity<List<MicroServiceClass>> res = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, responseType);
List<MicroServiceClass> list = res.getBody();
```

Comment: How to access the Object type fields values (please see EDIT)

Comment: Are you getting `List<MicroServiceClass> list = res.getBody();` list this way ?

Comment: rather this way  `ResponseEntity<Object> AllRoomsInfos = FlatComponent.getAllRooms();`

Comment: and then  `Iterator<Object> roomsIterable = ((List<Object>) AllRoomsInfos.getBody()).iterator();`

Comment: @lopmkipm What is your class name ?  are you using my solution ?  Then you will get exact List of your class and can access member

Comment: My class name is Room but it is undefined in the current class where its type is Object.

Comment: Then directly use Room when call using resttemplete

Comment: Room class is not defined in the current microservice that's why

Comment: That's why I asked you in comments can you create this class here or not. Here what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171637/java-reflection-how-to-get-field-value-from-an-object-not-knowing-its-class

Comment: i saw that link (thanks ! ) but it's returing an exception field non existent ! on the `getField("id")` call

Comment: Did you get your answer of this question ?