# How to get a value from a generic Object

Tags: java, spring

I have the following request with these fields:

Payment (Type Payment) -> Parameters (Type Object).
I know this Parameters class has these fields:

- token (String)
- type (String)
- cvv (String)

I´m trying to have access to the field *token* through `request.getPayment().getParameters()` but I don't really know how to make it work. I found something related to Reflection but I don´t really know how it can work.

I've tried something like but I still don't know howo to fetch this String "token":

```
   Field field = org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findField(String.class, "token");
   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        
   String token = field.get(request.getPayment().getParameters().????) ????
```

Comment: If the class has these fields then it must provide some way to access them, surely?

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that you will always have these fields in this generic object, you can just use casting:

```
class PaymentParameter {
   String token;
   String type;
   String cvv;

   ... // getters & setters or Lombok stuff
}
...
var paymentParameters = (PaymentParameters) request.getPayment().getParameters();
```

You can read more about casting [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting#downcasting) and [here](http://www.w3processing.com/index.php?subMenuLoad=java/oop/ObjectCasting.php).

Please be aware that casting can throw `ClassCastException`. So you have to cover this case in your code.

The second option is that your request is a JSON string, then you can use Jackson to convert it to the map or object. This topic is covered also on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).

Comment: I know that, but I don´t want to create a new class if possible.

Comment: In that case please check this anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16172206/1110241